# Loop over ModelView in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created razor forms that do a `@foreach` to loop over the model and produce my rows.  Now I am trying to to the same thing over a ViewModel, and I get the following error.

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyProject.Models.SupportContact'. 
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
```

My @model is being passed in as `IQueryable(MyProject.Models.SupportContactFormView)`, and `SupportContact` is part of that ViewModel, but I can't seem to reference it in the model.

I can do this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model ) {
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupportContact.Contact)
```

But then I will get the error above when it actually try to process my cshtml.  I have tried to do:

```
@foreach (MyProject.Models.SupportContact item in Model ) {}
```

But I can't drill down thru the model to get the SupportContacts.  How can I get to a my `SupportContact` class inside my ViewModel?

Thanks

Edit:

Here is the ViewModel declaration:

```
public class SupportContactFormView
{
    public SupportContact SupportContact { get; private set; }
    public SelectList Priorities { get; private set; }
    public SelectList ContactTypes { get; private set; }
    public String Group_COde { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you have have a DisplayTemplate set up for `Contact` ?

Comment: Show your `SupportContactFormView` code

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: No DisplayTemplate has been setup.  I has EF generate the scaffolding for SupportContact controller.

Comment: @Limey - why are you using `DisplayFor()` if you don't have a DisplayTemplate?

Comment: @EkoostikMartin: that is just came from the default scaffolding.  It is valid in other areas.  Maybe VS made a displayTemplate and I just don't know it (I'm kinda new to MVC)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, I would create a viewmodel specifically for that view and set it up like so

**ViewModel Class**

```
public class IndexViewModel
{
    public IList<SupportContact > SupportContacts { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var viewModel = new IndexViewModel();
    viewModel.SupportContacts = IQueryableListOfContacts.ToList();

    return View(viewModel)
}
```

**View**

```
@model IndexViewModel
@foreach (var contact in Model.SupportContacts) {
     @Html.DisplayFor(_ => contact.Contact)
```

You need to play around a bit with the code, as I doubt I have the property names/action method name correct first time, but I hope you get the basic idea. Create a viewmodel class that the view file makes use of, and dump the contact details into a List. That will make it easier for you.

EDIT:

Actually, I think I got the wrong end of the stick here. The error "Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyProject.Models.SupportContact'. 
Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context." means that there is something wrong with your LINQ data.

Are you using Entity Framework or Linq2SQL? Ignore my answer about the viewmodel appraoch, your actual issue is LINQ related. Try iterating over the list of contacts in an ActionMethod instead e.g.

```
public ActionMethod Index()
{
    foreach (var contact in whateveryourcontactslistis) {
    }

    // ....    
}
```

If you still have a problem here, then it's your LINQ data at fault.

Comment: but wouldn't that just be the equivalent of just querying my SupportContact directly and sending that?  I need to be able to pull the ViewModel so I can get all the SelectList information for building my dropdownlists.

Comment: Key idea was to use a List rather then an IQueryable. For some reason, that way was having a problem. Try using a List<SupportContact> for the contacts instead, if that does not work, then let us know any exceptions, etc.

Comment: Ok, Let me see about converting it.

Comment: You kind of lost me on your edit.  So I should loop over my contacts in the  ActionResult for Index, but what should i do to it in the loop?  Just move to an IList?

Comment: It is most definitely something with my EF.  I check my data right before it was being sent to the model, and I'm getting the error there as well.  Need to dig into this one a little more.

Comment: This is tricky to explain without my being next to you :) Basically, your list of contacts - are you able to do something like `var list = yourListOfContacts.ToList();` Do you have an existing list of contacts that you can call `.ToList()` on them? The contacts that your are passing to the view?

Comment: Ok, so the issue was that during my linq to Entities query, I was trying to make a default record if no results returned.  Once i removed that and handled it afterwards, I get a different error, but one i would expect:  The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MyProject.Models.SupportContact]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[MyProject.Models.SupportContactFormView]'.